# Connecting to MySQL using PHP and Inserting $Variables

Tags: php, mysql

This code will not work- it says I have unexpected T_STRING Error on the line with **..its really bugging me..its probably something basic but Im a bit of a noob so any help would be great!

```
<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'main';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$tbl_name="business";

$country = $_POST['country'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$business_name= $_POST['business_name'];
$address1= $_POST['address1'];
$address2= $_POST['address2'];
$city= $_POST['city'];
$county= $_POST['county'];
$zip= $_POST['zip'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$web_address = $_POST['web_address'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$open= $_POST['open'];
$closed= $_POST['closed'];
$description=$_POST['description']

**mysql_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass") or die (mysql_error());**
mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die (mysql_error());


$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name VALUES                      ('','$country','$name','$business_name','$address1','$address2','$city','$county','$zip','$    phone','$web_address','$email','$password','$open','$closed','$description');";
$result=mysql_query($sql_insert);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.  At a minimum, you _must_ call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on each `$_POST` input:  `$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);`

Comment: As a general tip, when MySQL gives you a syntax-type error like that one, the error is often on the line BEFORE the one it mentions.

Comment: And yes, this code is extremely unsafe. If you're not familiar with SQL injection, it means that someone could submit a "name" that has SQL code in it, and get your database to do something like show them other users' password hashes or delete all your tables. See http://bobby-tables.com/php.html for better alternatives (I like PDO, using the syntax at the very bottom of the page).

Comment: Take thirty minutes and [learn PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). It'll save you from a whole world of hurt.

Comment: Cheers i'll look at PDO's,and security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is a missing semicolon to close this line:

`$description=$_POST['description']`

Answer (score 2):

you need to add an `;` after `$description=$_POST['description']`

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're missing a semicolon on the preceding line of code:

```
$description=$_POST['description']
```

PHP error messages tend to give the line number where the parser noticed the issue, not where the issue occurred.

Comment: I have fixed this error but I am receiving the Error message-it is not connecting to the database. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the exact error message you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

Missing semicolon here...

```
$closed= $_POST['closed'];
$description=$_POST['description']; <------

**mysql_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass") or die (mysql_error());**
mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die (mysql_error());
```